# How to reuse kendo ui remote binding datasource (change transport.read.data then refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I want to ask if it's possible to reuse an remote binding `kendo.data.Datasource` instead of create new one with new parameters.

My scenario is that I have a search box and a list view. When user entering in search box, a request is sent to server with parameter of the search box value. I was able to make it works fine by create new `kendo.data.Datasource` each `keyup` event but memory became a concern to me.

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  searchId: "", // searchbox value
  searchResult: null, // search result listview datasource
  searchFnc: function() { // search function
    // QUESTION: is there any way to update the current datasource object 
    // to refresh the list view instead of create new object?
    // something like: 
    // this.set("searchResult.options.transport.read.data.postId", this.get("searchId"));

    this.set("searchResult", new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            postId: this.get("searchId")
          }
        }
      }
    }));
  }
});

kendo.bind($("#myView"), viewModel);
```

```css
.item {
  list-style: none;
}
.item span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40px;
}
#myListView {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



<div id="myView">
  <label>Enter Post ID (1,2,3,4...)
    <label>
      <br/>
      <span class="k-textbox k-space-right">
    <input type="text" data-value-update="keyup" data-bind="value: searchId, events: {keyup: searchFnc}"/>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="k-icon k-i-search" data-bind="click: searchFnc">&nbsp;</a>
  </span>

      <ul id="myListView" data-role="listview" data-bind="source: searchResult" data-template="template-search-result">
      </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template-search-result">
  <li class="item">
    <span>#: postId #</span>
    <span>#: id #</span>
    <span>#: name #</span>
  </li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? [change-datasource-url-on-grid](http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-datasource-url-on-grid). It is using a function as similar as yours ( `options.transport.read.url` ) from kendo. Then it is updated with `.refresh()`.

Comment: I actually tried this at first but doesn't work. Maybe because I'm using listview?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Japi/1mf9qzv5/)

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    searchId: 1,
    searchResult: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: function() {
                    return "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" + viewModel.get("searchId") + "/comments"
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
         }
    }),
    searchFnc: function() {
        this.searchResult.read();
    }

});

kendo.bind($("#myView"), viewModel);
```

Comment: I also tried this but `this` is accessible at `postId: this.get("searchId")`. Actually it's something else other than `viewModel`. I don' know if I'm missing something. Can you put up a working snippet? Just clone mine and edit.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You'll have to include search id straight to url. I did edit my answer.

Comment: It didn't work at all. I believe variable `viewModel` is not defined yet in `url: function() { ... }` nor `this` refers to the `viewModel` itself. Your fiddle also doesn't work even after I fix the REST url. (The correct one is `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1`)